# Reading a text file without using getline() in C++

Tags: c++, performance, file-io, getline

From what I learned, in order to analyze a text file, the go-to method is to analyze it line by line, which is easy and efficient.

However, when we're dealing with a huge file that has all the text in one line, the getline() function definitely would not be efficient at all. I'm wondering if there's any other efficient method to analyze this huge file?

The only thing I have in mind is to store this huge line into a string variable, and then cut it to singles words. But this still does not sound efficient at all.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: "the `getline()` function definitely would not be efficient at all." How do you know? You have to profile it, and decide whether it's efficient enough for your purposes. C++ standard library is highly optimized, so you may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: What specific problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Das: I take back that statement. I think I'm just looking for a better method than getline(). It's the most straight forward and standard way, but I think there should probably be a better method than it.

Comment: Barry: This problem involves a txt file with the size over 600MB. And I'm asked to find particular patterns(e.g. words with all upper case letters) within the file and print them out. The getline() function seems to be really slow with such a big file, so I'm trying to find a better way to go through the file and find the patterns I want along the way.

Comment: The devil's in the details, which is why showing the first couple hundred characters of the file would help people provide useful advice.  For example, fit the words are white-space separated, you can simply use `while (file_stream >> next_word_string) ...`.  If there are commas or other separators, or some things you consider "words" that contain white-space (e.g. "ice cream"), then you'll need fancier handling too.

Comment: There is no "go to method". No one woud use `getline` where `getline` does not make sense. How to read a file depends on its *contents* not on what is fashionable.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Tony! The while loop method totally worked for me! I can now analyze the file word by word without going through the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::istream::get(char *, std::streamsize)` to read large chunks of the file into a suitably-large buffer, and then process the file piecemeal, in large chunks.

Alternatively, there can be operating system-specific ways that can be used too. On Linux, a read-only `mmap()` of a file could be used to plow through it, with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: The while(stream >> next_word) method solves my problem as Tony said above. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is basically just a shortcut for handling line-breaks - or **other** characters! So if your file has some delimiters (semicolon for example), you can use

```
std::getline(fileStream, stringToSave, ';');
```

As for performance - you just gotta try what works in your case.